# Math behind path tracing

Tags: graphics, mathematical-analysis, mathematical-programming

I seem to remember seeing somewhere (many years ago) a writeup of the math behind calculating the outline of Metafont glyphs.  The basic idea is you have a "pen" that is a circle or oval, that you then trace along a cubic spline.  The question then is can you define the curve that is the outline of that stroked glyph.

Anyone know where I could find such a writeup?

Comment: Perhaps this question would find a better place on tex.se.

Comment: These are in the most cases Bézier curves quadratic or cubic, there is a way of offsetting such curves, but it is somewhat cumbersome. In some cases it is simply not possible, because non-rational splines cannot represent conics. If you have pure computer graphics question it is proper here or at graphics.SE, otherwise it is reference request and might be good at tex.

Comment: [type1](https://www.tug.org/TUGboat/tb19-3/hoek1.pdf), 
[THE BOOK](http://www.ctex.org/documents/shredder/src/mfbook.pdf)